# peltier not cooling anything

Tags: voltage

Hello I am trying to use 30 "tec-1 12706" peltiers along with my geothermal ground loop to cool machines. I have (2) banks of 15 in series and the two bank parallel to each other electrically. Power from simple 600v ac/dc full wave rectifier and (2) 1000 uf larger radial caps with high ripple duty rating. Scoped the power is 154.5 vdc with ripple equal to a normal quality regulated psu. 15 peltiers in series x 12vdc = 180vdc so 154.5 puts applied voltage at 10.23 each. I also measured across the series jumps to confirm. normale rating  I have used 7 200mm water blocks to form a sandwich. 4 block are supplied the entrance closed loop water from my geothermal at an incredibly stable 52.2 deg f. the other 3 blocks are connected to a manifold the supply 5 200mm radiators with 120mm 1300 rpm case fans. these radiators are mounted inside items like my server, my workstation, a cnc mill controller ect. Total heat load measured by btu = 500 x flow rate of water x difference in inlet outlet water using geothermal or totals 743 btu hour. Not much. If the peltiers are supply endless cooling at 52 f and the peltiers are all oriented correctly with undervolting why is there only 1 deg reduction from cooling water running through radiators. non energized cooling water, not geothermal is 78 deg f. that's cold side water blocks to radiators. this drops in 10 mins to 77f than creeps up to 80 f after and hour. the heat output to the ground loop is around 1200 watt or 4094 btu/h they seem to only make heat on one side with barely any cooling on cold side. non of them are heating on both sides. amps range from 3.4 to 38 each module. everything is in spec but the out come. Any ideas. I also jump stated the cooling process by cooling the water in system to desired level of 45 f. Then energized the tecs. 1 hour later back up to 80f. Flow rate to hot blocks are 2.1 gpm  divided by 4 blocks equal flow for .525 gpm each with the same divided by 3 for the cold side .7 gpm.

If i'm correct 30 tec- 12706 us made at 10.23 volts at 3.8 amps = 1368 watt equals 4667.809 btu hour, which i have on the hotside. and assuming 30 percent loss where is the 3267.467 btu/h cooling I'm not receiving going? something up and I don't see the solution. The tec-1 get cold by them selves but not as a thermally coupled unit . I used arctic silver and check their smear patterned for equal coverage, and the stack of water blocks are clamped using upper and lower 3/8 plate stainless and surrounded with 4mm stainless threaded rod. nut on bottom and thermally decoupled compression springs above using 7 lbs force each x 18. I got those numbers from manufacturer.    sorry for running on, but I intend to provide as much data as I can. This is a hobby lever build, but constructed by a profession in the field of power gen and geothermal tech. Thank you in advance for any help, I'm stuck?????????

Comment: Can you add paragraph breaks, fix the capitalization, and summarise that?  How much current is really passing through the peltiers? (Measured with an ammeter.)

Comment: How much cooling power do you expect to get per TEC module? Have you tried one on its own" How many watts of cooling does it take to cool 0.7GPM by 1 degree?

Comment: please remove the question marks at the end ... the last sentence is a statement, not a question

Comment: Peltiers are terrible for constant thermal load cooling, and usually it will just exacerbate the cooling issues as you then have to move the original thermal energy away along with the thermal energy produced by the modules themselves. Assuming you haven't killed any of them yet by insufficient cooling, you most likely haven't done the thermal engineering correctly to calculate the true thermal flux, the total thermal energy needing to be removed, and the overall power efficiency of that method.

Comment: A better question is, what is your intent? Why are you not able to cooling your devices by water cooling and a radiator setup? Do you require below ambient?...etc.

P.S. Apologies if these have been answered in your post, it is definitely messy and hard to read.

Comment: _" these radiators are mounted inside items like my server, my workstation, a cnc mill controller ect...desired level of 45 f"_ - why do you want this low temperature?

Comment: forgive my grammar, current is 3.8 amps rms. voltage 10.23.

Answer (score 1):

> Hello I am trying to use 30 "tec-1 12706" peltiers along with my geothermal ground loop to cool machines.

This is a bad idea.  At kilowatt class loads, a simple compressor setup will be cheaper and more effective because the coefficient of performance of a compressor is several times higher than a TEC, meaning that vastly less energy must be supplied and less heat removed.  It will probably also be cheaper as you can often find working compressor systems in old AC units or refrigerators available for free, which as a hobbyist you may find appealing.

> The tec-1 get cold by them selves but not as a thermally coupled unit

Have you calculated what the expected temperature differential should be?  A 1 degree drop may be reasonable given the small capacity of most TECs and the large number of things you mention hooking up to the loop.

Comment: Indeed, TECs operate more efficiently with smaller temperature differentials between both sides. If the machine temp is 85degF, supplying it with 45degF cooling water is not making it run any better, it's making it *worse*. This is why the cooling temp always climbs up to right under the machine temp.

Comment: supplying cold water is only to provide the best cooling possible for the hot side. In place of heat sink that can't cool below ambient. I even completely removed the heat load by diverting peltier cold side water to recirc only 1 gal. in insulated class a water tank. there is no delta, quite the opposite I have controller every element and they just don't cool. not even 50 watts out of 1368..